# How can i upload my custom icons in ionic framework?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

i'm creating my ionic application, and it's my first application, i need to add my custom icons in this application, i cut out all icons i need in photo shop, then i used them by this way:

```
.my-star-icon {
  content: url('/img/selected-icon.png');
  width: 22px;
}
```

I did my app navigation using tabs:

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top" id="tab">

  <ion-tab title="Feed" icon="ion-social-rss"
    href="#/app/feed">
    <ion-nav-view name="feed-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Selected" icon="my-star-icon"
    href="#/app/selected">
    <ion-nav-view name="selected-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Actions" icon="ion-ios-list-outline"
    href="#/app/actions">
    <ion-nav-view name="actions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Charts" icon="ion-arrow-graph-up-right"
    href="#/app/charts">
    <ion-nav-view name="charts-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="More" icon="ion-more"
    href="#/app/more">
    <ion-nav-view name="more-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

When i adding instead icon name my class it appears in my navigation menu, but it works strange, no focus and hover styles does not work, can't understand why, maybe i should somehow download this icons in my ionic application?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this service

https://icomoon.io/

it provides css files and fonts that easy include in project

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
  <ion-tab title="Actions" icon="actions" href="#/app/actions">
    <ion-nav-view name="actions-tab"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

Then in the css:

```
.actions{
  background-image: url('/img/actions.png');
 }

/* optional */
.tab-item .icon {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

And adjust sizing if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

//this code is used to load custom icons in ionic 3: //IN app.sccs:

```
        ion-icon {
  &[class*="custom-"] {
    mask-size: contain;
    mask-position: 50% 50%;
    mask-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
  }
  &[class*="custom-profilepac"] {
    // the following commented line is the way to load the icon
    // <ion-icon name="custom-profilepac"></ion-icon>
    background: url(../assets/icon/profilePac.svg);
  }
  &[class*="custom-profile"] {
    // <ion-icon name="custom-profile"></ion-icon>
    background: url(../assets/icon/profilePro.svg);
  }
}
```